# Android: Check internet connection - returns true (incorrectly)

Tags: android, android-networking, android-internet

To check for internet connectivity, i am using this code:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isAvailable() && netInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

This is the most commonly used code i found everywhere - however it is not working reliably.

This is returning true, although i am unable to use internet.
Other apps on my mobile correctly give message: 'Can't connect to internet'.

**EDIT 1** 
It appears that it returns true when internet connection is there - even though it is unusable for some reason. 
If i switch off the Mobile Data/Internet on my phone - then this method correctly returns false.

Comment: i think internet is available to you but the strength of connection is quite low or you are unable to exchange data due to this bad connection

Comment: The problem is you are connected to the "NETWORK" but "INTERNET" is "NOT AVAILABLE".

Comment: Pramod> Yes that seems to be the case. I have added additional info to the question.

Comment: does it work if you remove `&& netInfo.isAvailable()`?

Comment: Apurva> no - that does not help

Answer (score 2):

Those all will tell you if your device is connected or not, they do not tell you the internet status...
For that you should use this code...

```
 private boolean isOnline() {
            try{
                // ping to googlevto check internet connectivity
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 80);
                socket.connect(socketAddress, 3000);
                socket.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 // internet not working
                 return false
            }
 }
```

You must do this in async task or it will give you network on main thread exception...
I am assuming you are already calling isOnline method in async task.

Well if you are not using this in an async task,
You must use it here like this....

for example you want to go to xyz activity only if internet available

```
private class GoToXYZActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     boolean internetAvailable;
     protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AFTER ONPREEXECUTE
         //YOUR NETWORK OPERATION HERE
         internetAvailable = inOnline();
         return null;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         //THIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED FIRST
         //DO OPERATION LIKE SHOWING PROGRESS DIALOG PRIOR TO BEGIN NETWORK OPERATION
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute();
         //TNIS METHOD WILL BE CALLED AT LAST AFTER DOINBACKGROUND
         //DO OPERATION LIKE UPDATING UI HERE
         if (internetAvailable)
             /// goto xyz activity
         else
             /// toast - no internet
     }
 }
```

And on click event you must call this method

```
 new GoToXYZActivity().execute();
```

Comment: Is it ok to explicitly open sockets in android - any implications of that?

Comment: To replicate the problem again - I need to find a way to get my phone again in that zombie state - where it shows mobile data connection available, but its actually unusable - will revert after some tests a little later :)

Comment: @Jasper As far as sockets are concerned, its OK to use them... And the solution will definately work as i implemented this in my app and tested this when wifi showed limited connectivity :)  Please mark it as correct if this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: seriously.. :D I was delayed by 7 seconds.. :( :D

Comment: no problem i am currently working on gps that's why i am using this method to check internet connection in my application where you are working currently.........