# Android Network Check Unreliable

Tags: android, connectivity

It seems that I'm facing an issue where the network check isnt reliable. What I mean by that is that it sometimes returns true when actually network isn't available.

This happens in real world scenarios when you go underground and loose signal, the phone properly reports it showing no bars but the check will still return true.

I'm using the following code:

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
    boolean isNetworkAvailalbe = (activeNetworkInfo != null);
```

I'm looking for the most bullet proof way to implement a reliable network check, any recommendations ?

Comment: Check this Thread, Same question is already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448197/android-check-internet-connection-returns-true-incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

try with this..

```
public static boolean checkNetworkRechability(Context mContext) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isInternetAvailable();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        Log.i("TAG", "isInternetAvailable start");
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(new URL("google.com").getHost());


            String ip = ipAddr.getHostAddress();
            if (ip.equals("")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Log.i("TAG", "IP Address : " + ip);
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I feel it is a good iteration on the answer provided by @Sandro. Do you ever encounter that this method takes longer to execute when testing in the field?

Comment: In investigating this answer - it seems a bit cumbersome in a sense that this now must be executed in a separate thread as otherwise a NetworkOnMainTreadException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

On the Android Developer portal you can find more information: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: Thank you for this, I am testing and will get back on whether this fixed the issue.

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay in getting back on this. Needed to actually get out in the field to test this. And I have to admit it happens less often but still occurs. So this does not fix the problem unfortunately. Thanks.